# Scalar fields of graphs

Tags: statistical-mechanics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, graph-theory, network

I am trying to find literature on the propagation of scalar fields over random graphs.

Think of a network of ideal resistors (with a given degree distribution), with a voltage source at a random node. The graph is grounded at infinity.

How could we characterise the distribution of voltage intensity over the nodes of the graph?

Comment: Do you mean like the Ising model? I am not sure what you mean by a "scalar field" here, although admittedly I am more a mathematician than a physicist.

Comment: There are nice probabilistic representations in terms of random walks. See for example [this very-easy-to-read book](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/walks/walks.pdf) by Doyle and Snell. There are many more advanced references on this topic.

Comment: By scalar field I mean any scalar value per node such as an oscillation amplitude or the voltage level. Maybe I am misusing the term, I am no physicist myself.
I will look at the book you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

> How could we characterise the distribution of voltage intensity over the nodes of the graph?

The voltages are just numbers assigned to the nodes. Every node gets some number, which might be further visualized, for example, as a bubble plot: the larger voltage the larger bubble size.

For better visualization, addition of currents might be helpful. Knowing voltages on two nodes and resistance between them, the current is obtained via the Ohm law. Both voltage bubbles and current lines could give a nice visualization, just need to play with scales (normal vs exponential).

> I am trying to find literature on the propagation of scalar fields over random graphs.

Literature on the percolation theory might be helpful.

Comment: My question was not oriented on visualizing. I am looking for a mathematical characterisation, such as a voltage level as a function of the node's degrees for example.